# Invoke-Item hangs only through PSRemoting

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I'm trying to make a script that copies a .lnk file to a computer and then uses `Invoke-Item` to open it on the machine.  When I do it on my local computer it works fine, even when I run PowerShell as a different user.  When I attempt to run `Invoke-Item` inside any sort of PSRemoting session it just hangs.  No error or anything.  I have tried multiple ways of doing it on the script, but even if I open up a PowerShell window and `Enter-PSSession`, then run `Invoke-Item` "C:\shortcut.lnk", it still doesn't work.

```
Copy-Item \\RemoteServer\shortcut.lnk \\TargetMachine\C$\shortcut.lnk

$S = New-PSSession -ComputerName TargetMachine

Invoke-Command -Session $S -ScriptBlock { Invoke-Item "C:\shortcut.lnk" }
```

Comment: Please [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Comment: `New-PSSession` doesn't run in the user context.i.e. no matter what you run, nothing will show up to the logged in user. If you need to run in the user session, you have to look at something like PSExec

Comment: A link file is only a shortcut to a file on your local computer. If you copy the .lnk file to another computer, the link is no longer valid. If you right click on the .lnk file in File Explorer and select Properties, on the Shortcut tab you will see the file the .lnk file points to in the Target box. For example, the target may be "C:\Temp\myfile.dat". On your remote computer, the .lnk file will think it is pointing to C:\Temp\myfile.dat" on your remote computer. If you are trying to access the file on your local computer from the remote computer you will need to set up a file share.